# PHP Configuration class

Tags: php, configuration

Created this little config class, any room for improvements? Think I have done an alright job but would like to know if any improovements could be made?

```
<?php
defined("SECURE") or exit('Please define SECURE keyword to continue.');
class config
{
    private $configValues;
    private $configFile;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $configValues = array();
    }

    public function loadConfiguration($configFile = "C:\Users\ashle\Miracle\config\config.ini")
    {
        if (!file_exists($configFile))
            loadDefault();

        $content = file($configFile);
        foreach ($content as $line)
            $this->setConfig(explode("=", $line)[0], explode("=", $line)[1]);
    }

    private function loadDefault()
    {
        /* DEFAULT CONFIG SETTINGS!!
           THIS SHOULD NOT BE THE CASE... */

        setConfig("database.host", "localhost");
        setConfig("database.username", "root");
        setConfig("database.password", "");
        setConfig("database.title", "mydb");
        setConfig("database.port", "3306");
    }

    private function setConfig($name, $value)
    {
        $this->configVlaues[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function getConfig($name)
    {
        return $this->configValues[$name];
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Things that just pop up in my mind when seeing the code (more of the architecture and robustness rather than language constructs):

**1) Harcoding path to ini file**

The path might have a meaning in your development environment, but it will mean nothing in a test or production environment. I would set it in an included file and use it from there. Something like:

```
$defaultConfigFilePath = "C:\Users\ashle\Miracle\config\config.ini";
```

in `loadConfiguration`
    $configFile = !isset($configFile) ? $defaultConfigFilePath : $configFile;

Hopefully, they will introduce a [coalesce operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary) soon to simply write:

```
$configFile = $configFile ?? $defaultConfigFilePath;
```

**2) Error handling**

`loadConfiguration` function does not handle any incorrect formatting. Any line which is not in the format name=value will not be imported correctly.

You can explode into an `$lineArray` and check if elements are defined and exactly two.

**3) A more powerful config reader**

This is a good exercise, but ini files have a more complex format that seems to be handled by [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, one thing that popped into my head to ask was what is the speed on something like this like? I mean would it be faster to just make a file and havea variable for each config item? Also security.. is this more secure locating the config file outside the website folder?